# classList.remove() is removing the class but not its contents

Tags: javascript, css, bootstrap-4

I am trying to add one class and remove another class on clicking of the start quiz button. While the 'info_box' class is successfully added the 'start_btn' class does not get removed, it just changes the position(from flex to no flex).
This is the Html

```
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="start_btn" >
            <button type="button" class="startBtn">Start Quiz</button>
        </div>
        <div class="row info_box">
            <div class="col-md-6">
             <!--Rest of the code-->
```

This is the CSS

```
/*START BUTTON BOX*/
.start_btn {
    height:80vh;
    display: flex;
    justify-content:center;
    align-items:center;
    
}


.startBtn{
    font-size: 25px;
    font-weight: 500;
    color: var(--clr-steelBlue);
    padding: 15px 30px;
    outline: none;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background: var(--clr-white);
    cursor: pointer;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 
    0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
    pointer-events: auto;
  
}

.startBtn:focus{
    background-color: var(--clr-steelBlue);
    color:var(--clr-white);
    outline: var(--clr-steelBlue);
}

.showInfoBox.info_box{
  display: flex;
}

/* INFO BOX*/
.info_box {
    height:100vh;
    display: flex;
    justify-content:center;
    align-items:center;
    display:none;
    
}
```

This is the javascript

```
const startbtn = document.querySelector(".start_btn");
const infoBox = document.querySelector(".info_box");

startbtn.addEventListener('click', function(){

    startbtn.classList.remove("start_btn");
    infoBox.classList.add("showInfoBox");
})
```

I checked the developers tool and it is like this. The class start_btn is not there but the button which is inside the start_btn div is still present
[image]

I tried removing the button separately before removing the start_btn box but it does not work
I tried making a separate class to remove the start_btn like this but it doesn't work

```
.hide.start_btn{
 z-index:-1; 
  pointer-events: none;

}
```

What can I do to remove the start_btn class? Thank You!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does what it's intended to do: removing the class from an element. If you want to remove that element from the DOM, use [`remove()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/remove) method.